# deserialize optional in kotlin from string in redis

Tags: kotlin, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm trying to deserialize an optional that I save as a string in redis, but I always return a hashmap.
I'm instantiating my object mapper

```
 private  var objectMapper: ObjectMapper= ObjectMapper().registerModule(KotlinModule())
        .registerModule( Jdk8Module())
.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
```

serialize asi

```
  redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("key3", objectMapper.writeValueAsString(value))
```

and I am deserializo asi:

```
var result1 = objectMapper.readValue<Optional<T>>(valueCache!!)
```

the result is

[image]

where T is a User class

class UserRole : Serializable {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
var id: Long = 0

@Min(value = 1)
@JsonProperty("role_id")
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
var roleId: Long = 0
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What you are reporting doesn't look right, I tried your code and it works as expected. Please check the following code snippet:

```
data class Role(val id: String, val name: String)
data class User(val id: String, val name: String, val email: String, val phone: String, val roles: List<Role>)


val objectMapper: ObjectMapper = ObjectMapper().registerModule(KotlinModule())
    .registerModule(Jdk8Module())
    .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)

val json = """
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "John Smith",
        "email": "john@smith@mail.com",
        "phone": "+1-541-754-3010",
        "roles": [
            {"id": "1", "name": "User"},
            {"id": "1", "name": "Editor"},
            {"id": "1", "name": "Admin"}
        ]
    }
""".trimIndent()

val result = objectMapper.readValue<Optional<User>>(json)
println(result)
```

**Output**

> Optional[User(id=1, name=John Smith, email=john@smith@mail.com, phone=+1-541-754-3010, roles=[Role(id=1, name=User), Role(id=1, name=Editor), Role(id=1, name=Admin)])]

And the debug inspection indeed report the correct types

[image]

Comment: yeah but my entity have many attributes                         val json = """{"id":1,"email":"diego.suarez968@hola.com","phone":"74500771","password":"holamundo","name":"diego suarez","company_id":1,"first_name":"diego","last_name":"suarez","is_active":true,"is_logged":true,"user_roles":[],"user_company_services":[],"orders":[]}"""  the problem is when try deseralizar orders or user_roles because the list is empty

Comment: Then your question is not clear enough, you should define a `data class` for each one of your entities, like `data class Role(...)` and `data class User(..., roles: List<Role>)`

Comment: yeah, i actually i have a data class Role and user i have user_roles

Comment: But it looks like you are not deserializing correctly, do you have a User data class like the one I show in my answers and using `objectMapper.readValue<Optional<User>>(json)` to deserialize it??

Comment: @dasuma I updated my answer to reflect my previous comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185427/discussion-between-omar-mainegra-and-dasuma).